# Model instance not returning methods

Tags: php

I'm learning about PHP MVC logic and to understand about how they works I'm playing writing a basic framework. I wrote a controller and a model class, but when I'm loading the model class into the controller I'm not being able to run the model methods.

Below is an example code:

```php
<?php

class Controller {
    protected $model;

    protected function load_model($model) {
        if (class_exists($model)){
            return $this->model[$model] = new $model();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected function get_model($model) {
        if (is_object($model)) {
            return $this->model[$model];
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

class FooModel {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Class loaded";
    }
    public function echo_mess(){
        echo "Function run";
    }
}


class BarController extends Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load_model("FooModel");      
    }

    public function result() {
        $this->get_model("FooModel")->echo_mess();
    }
}

$obj = new BarController();
echo "<br />";
$obj->result();
```

I could test and got the "class loaded" message when the class was called and hopefully instantiated.

Can you point the flaw in the above? and get the result() print the function message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is actually quite simple - you pass a string to the :

```php
protected function get_model($model) {
```

so the line:

```php
if (is_object($model)) {
```

is invalid.

In your code it should actually be:

```php
if (isset($this->model[$model]) && is_object($this->model[$model])) {
```

as you check if an instance of a model provided by the name is already in your array inside the controller. YET be sure to notice that in your code architecture you can have only one instance per model of a class within the controller: not sure if that is what you want.

I understand that you are learning here about inheritance and patterns, but I strongly advise to move to real-world examples with good documentation - for example check the docs of Symfony framework and start to build something within it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I had the thought about the string, since is_object evaluates to boolean if the variable is an object, but yes as you mentioned, the purpose was to avoid multiple instances, if the check is removed, the method is returned withouth a problem

Comment: The check is intended to confirm the class is already instantiated